# How to execute code from a Module that resides in Microsoft Office Access Class Object

Tags: ms-access, vba

Is it possible to execute code that is apart of a Form in MS Access from an outside module? What would be the method to call in VBA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's definitely possible. It would have to be a public sub or function and the form would have to be loaded at the time.

```
Forms("FormName").SubOrFunction
```